# Customize the Bottom Bar in NavigationBar Controller

Tags: uinavigationbar

I have embedded Navigation Controller in UITable View Controller.
From the Navigation Controller, On the Simulated Metrics, I change the Bottom Bar from inferred to Translucent Black Tab Bar.

So, On the UITable View Controller, I have a navigation bar at top, and a tap bar and bottom.

i include one method to AppDelegate as follow:

```
    func customizeAppearance() {

    let tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor        
}
```

The navigation bar is successfully changed to what I want.
How to customize the color of bottom Bar.

I don't want to insert a tab bar into my UITableView, as it is not what I want cause when I tried and add a Tab Bar, it is just add itself to the last row in the table view which I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found how:
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor